# Making python script executable from any directory

Tags: python, linux, shell, command, executable

I have a python script, which has multiple command line options. I want to make this script runnable without having to type "python myscript.py" and without having to be in the same directory as the script. For example, if one installs git on linux, regardless of which directory the user is in, the user can do "git add X, etc..". So, an example input I would like is "myscript -o a,b,c -i" instead of "python myscript.py -o a,b,c -i". I already added "#! /usr/bin/env python" to the top of my script's code, which makes it executable when I type "./myscript", however I don't want the ./, and I want this to work from any directory.

Comment: You need to move it somewhere on your path, such as (typically) `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`. This is noted by `Then, make the script executable and put it somewhere in your PATH.` in the answer to the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the folder that contains the script to your system's $PATH variable (I assume you're on Linux). This variable contains all of the directories that are searched looking for a specific command. You can add to it by typing `PATH=/path/to/folder:$PATH`. Alternately, you need to move the script into a folder that's already in the $PATH variable (which is generally a better idea than messing with system variables).

Answer (score 0):

Your script needs to be in a location searchable via your `PATH`. On Unix/Linux systems, the generally accepted location for locally-produced programs and scripts that are not part of the system is `/usr/local/bin`. So, make sure your script is executable by running `chmod +x myscript`, then move it to the right place with `sudo mv myscript /usr/local/bin` (while in the directory containing `myscript`). You'll need to enter an admin's password, then you should be all set.